# WSO2 API Manager Integration with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to integrate Prometheus and Grafana with the latest version of WSO2 API Manager (4.2.0) and I'm following the below mentioned documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/streaming-integrator/setting-up-si-statistics-dashboards/

However, the documentation describes the integration of Prometheus and Grafana with the WSO2 Streaming Integrator. I was unable to find a proper documentation which describes the integration with the WSO2 API Manager.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the documentation should be describing the integration with WSO2 API Manager and not the WSO2 Streaming Integrator.